# radius of convergence of $\sum \limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {(3n+1)^{10}x^n} {2n^n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

How can I determine the radius of convergence of $\sum \limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {(3n+1)^{10}x^n} {2n^n}$?

I thought it should be easy by using the root test but I'm somehow failing to get a useful result.

Comment: Can you show some of what you have tried?

Comment: Yeah. Say for instance, have you tried the Ratio Test to establish the possible interval of convergence? Any thoughts?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern after thinking about it again it could actually make sense. I get $0<1$. Would my R then be $\infty$ ? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: @fatalError You get $0$ by using the Ratio Test?

Comment: @juniven No I'm talking about the root test. That was my question and I still want to know how to solve it this way before I look at other variants sorry.

Comment: Cauchy-Hadamard but also inspection: Look how fast the denominator grows relative to the numerator!

Comment: @fatlError Anyway, since then your answer (using Root Test) is $0$, it only means that the limit is not dependent on $x$. So, whatever values of $x$ you choose, the limit is $0$. This implies that the given power series holds for all real numbers $x$. Thus, the interval of convergence is $(-\infty,\infty)$ of which we can say radius $R$ is $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$R = \frac{1}{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac {(3n+1)^{10}} {2n^n}}} = \frac{1}{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(3n+1)^{10/n}}{\sqrt[n]{2}n}} = \infty$$
as $\lim_{n \to \infty} (3n+1)^{10/n}$ is finite and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2}n = \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ratio test is the one that in most cases give the easier answer :

Let be $\sum a_nx^n$ with $a_n=\frac{(3n+1)^{10}}{2n^n}$ and $\frac1R=lim|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$.

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(3n+4)^{10}2n^n}{(3n+1)^{10}2(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{(3n+4)^{10}}{(3n+1)^{10}}\times\frac{n^n}{n^{n+1}(1+\frac1n)^{n+1}}\sim1\times\frac{1}{ne}\to 0$ so the radius of convergence is infinite.

For the n-root test look at positrono answer, I should add a little bit of detail :

This $(3n+1)^\frac{10}{n}=\exp(\frac{10}{n}\,\ln(3n+1))=\exp(30\,\frac{\ln(3n+1)}{3n})\to 1$ since $\frac{\ln(u)}{u}\to_{+\infty} 0$.

And $\sqrt[n]{2n^n}=n\times\sqrt[n]2=n\times\exp(\frac{\ln(2)}{n})\sim n\times 1\sim n\to +\infty$ since $\frac{\ln(2)}{n}\to_{+\infty}0$

Answer (score 0):

This converges everywhere
since $n^n \ge n!$,
the
$(3n+1)^{10}$
does not affect convergence,
and
this converges at least as well
as $e^x$
which converges everywhere.